# Changing TCP ACK delay

Tags: networking, nodejs, tcp-ip

TCP ACK is described here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_delayed_acknowledgment

I know very little about this - I just learned about it via this ticket that I filed with Node.js:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21091

Basically I am using TCP to do IPC via localhost, but there's a big delay for each request.

This is the way to change the delay on RedHat apparently:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_for_real_time/7/html/tuning_guide/reducing_the_tcp_delayed_ack_timeout

is there a way to change this setting on Ubuntu?

Maybe like the wikipedia article says, use the `TCP_QUICKACK` option?

Comment: Any different if you use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?